# Как построить сущность для базы SQL исходя из данных эксель таблички?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Всем привет!

У меня есть следующая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на основе данных представленных в этой таблице создать сущность в БД? Мне нужна данная сущность, чтобы выбрать в ней верный коэффициент, зная возраст и стаж. Возраст и стаж рассчитывается исходя из данных в других таблицах.
Пример двух моих идей для создания сущности чуть ниже на картинке.
По первому варианту не вижу возможности отбирать данные, например, в случае если потребуется создать какой либо фильтр по стажу т.к. стаж здесь вшит в название колонок.
По второму варианту таблица получается сверх длиннющая.
Буду благодарен за ваши идеи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
    AGE         TINYINT       NOT NULL,
    EXPERIENCE  TINYINT       NOT NULL,
    COEFFICIENT NUMERIC(3, 2) NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT PK_AGE_EXPERIENCE PRIMARY KEY (AGE, EXPERIENCE),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_COEFFICIENT CHECK (COEFFICIENT >= 0)
)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin этот ответ считаю максимально прямым и компактным, без воды. Если у коллег появятся вопросы, буду ждать здесь, в комментариях к ответу.